# Alias in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
select eomonth('2023-01-01')
```

I want my alias to be picked by the function `MONTHNAME('2023-01-01')` so my output would be `2023-01-30` and my alias would be `January`

Comment: I really don't follow what you are trying to ask here, if I am honest. If you want to alias the column as `January` why not just suffix it with `AS January` or prefix it with `Janurary =`?

Comment: i may be using different date ranges so i dont want to hard code it

Comment: An alias *must* be a literal, so you have to hard code it. if you want to change the name of a column dynamically, that is a task for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(NoOfLates) 
   FROM AttendancePosting 
   WHERE NoOfLates = 1 AND EmpId = @EmpIDs and DATEPART(MONTH,AttDate)=DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, 4, @StartofYear)) ),0) 
 as [late availed]
This is my query in alias i want my month name to be picked

Comment: My statement doesn't change. An alias **must** be a literal. What ever you are actually trying to achieve is should be a job for your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DATENAME:

```
select eomonth('2023-01-01') ,DATENAME(MONTH, eomonth('2023-01-01') )
```

Dynamic alias:

```
declare @yourdate date = '2023-01-01'
declare @monthname nvarchar(20)=(select DATENAME(MONTH,@yourdate))
declare @SQL nvarchar(200) = concat('select eomonth(',quotename(@yourdate,char(39)),') as ',@monthname )
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

[image]

Add your query:

```
 declare @yourdate date = '2023-01-01'
 declare @monthname nvarchar(20)=(select DATENAME(MONTH,@yourdate))
 declare @anothersql nvarchar(500) = ',COALESCE((SELECT SUM(deductdays) FROM tbl_LeaveDeduction WHERE  CHARINDEX(quotename(CAST(EmpId AS varchar(10)),char(44)), @EmpIds) > 0 and  DATEPART(MONTH,DeductionDate)= DATEPART(MONTH,@StartofYear) ),0)'
 declare @SQL nvarchar(500) = concat('select eomonth(',quotename(@yourdate,char(39)),') as ',@monthname,@anothersql )
 exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: The `EOMONTH` isn't needed in the second expression, in truth. The name of the month is always the same, regardless of if the date is at the start, end, or middle of the month.

Comment: but i am getting alias null in this

Comment: My main concern is alias i want it dynamic

Comment: alias name is like a column name in result set. you cannot make it as dynamic , unless you are having dynamic sql. Why do you need dynamic alias name ?

Comment: Lev Gelman i want to add this in your query
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(deductdays)
     FROM tbl_LeaveDeduction
      WHERE  CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(EmpId AS varchar(10)) + ',', @EmpIds) > 0 and DATEPART(MONTH,DeductionDate)=DATEPART(MONTH,@StartofYear) ),0)

Comment: @user10888389 I added to answer, I can't run it, if you see some issue, you'll need to provide sample data here